# gatsby build → WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gatsby

I have implemented a login feature in gatsby using firebase auth.
I tested it with  `gatsby develop` and the login function worked fine.
However, when I ran the `gatsby build`, I got the following error message.

> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined

Can you please tell me how to solve this error?

---

I am using [gatsby-plugin-firebase](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-firebase/?=firebase).
And it has the following settings.

**gatsby-config.js**

```js
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-firebase",
      options: {
        credentials: {
          apiKey: "***",
          authDomain: "***",
          databaseURL: "***",
          projectId: "***",
          storageBucket: "***",
          messagingSenderId: "***",
          appId: "***",
        },
      },
    },
```

**gatsby-browser.js**

```js
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
```

**gatsby-ssr.js**

```js
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
```

`GoogleAuthProvider` is used as follows.

**SignIn.tsx**

```js
import firebase from "gatsby-plugin-firebase";

const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
const twitterProvider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();

const setProvider = (name: string) => {
  switch (name) {
    case "Google":
      return googleProvider
    case "Facebook":
      return facebookProvider
    case "Twitter":
      return twitterProvider
    default:
      return googleProvider
  }
}

const auth = firebase.auth();

const signInFunction = async (e) => {
  const provider = setProvider(e.currentTarget.name);
  await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  ...
}

const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={signInFunction} name="Google">Google</button>
      <button onClick={signInFunction} name="Twitter">Twitter</button>
      <button onClick={signInFunction} name="Facebook">Facebook</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think about how Gatsby works to understand what's going on. While `gatsby develop`'s compilation is handled by the browser, `gatsby build` is compiled in the server (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) where most of the functions that are available in the browser aren't in the server, [especially global object like `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

Basically, you can't require or import your providers at the build time because they're not already set. To bypass this limitation, you can create a custom hook (`useAuthState`) and use it like:

```
import firebase from "gatsby-plugin-firebase"
import useAuthState from ...

function MyComponent() {
const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(firebase); // NOT firebase.auth()

// ...
if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
if (user) return <p>Hi, {user.displayName}!</p>
if (error) //handle error

}
```

Your `useAuthState` hook:

```
import {useEffect, useReducer, useState} from "react";

export default function useAuthState(firebase) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(undefined);

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        (state, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "auth_state_changed":
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        user: action.user,
                        loading: false,
                    };
                case "error":
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        error: action.error,
                        loading: false,
                    };
            }
        },
        {
            user: undefined,
            loading: true,
            error: undefined,
        }
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        setAuth(firebase.auth());
    }, [firebase]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (auth === undefined) return;

        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(
            user => {
                dispatch({type: "auth_state_changed", user});
            },
            error => {
                dispatch({type: "error", error});
            }
        );

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, [auth]);
    return [state.user, state.loading, state.error];
```

*Note: credits to [Jeffrey Meng](https://gist.github.com/jeffreymeng)*

As you can see, you are using a `useEffect` hook that awaits for the Firebase connection to retrieve the needed data. This is waiting for the DOM tree to be loaded instead of being triggered at the build-time.

Resources:

- https://gist.github.com/jeffreymeng/78bd7f6b0f301fa5ef04359cd512222b
- https://github.com/alexluong/gatsby-packages/issues/21

Comment: Yes, the idea is to wait and don't load the auth code before the SSR ends.